# Getting first image from post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using [top 10 popular post](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/top-10/) to display the popular post. Some of my post have a custom image before the post content. What I want to display for the popular post thumbnail is to display that first custom image right before the post then subsequent post that do not have that header image will take the first image from the post content. Please advise thanks.

Hi my output is to display the custom header image image before the post content.

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+?src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*?>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches[1][0];

  if(empty($first_img)) {
    $first_img = "/path/to/default.png";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

This above code fetched the first image from content. But the custom image is not within the content. How do I implement that? The custom image is from ACF image and return in array format.

Comment: This is just a specification! Can you show us code?

Comment: `Please advise`...on what exactly? It's unclear what you are stuck with, what you've tried or what the problem is. This isn't a free write-my-code service, and we'll need a more specific issue to deal with anyway. Plus it's very hard to advise when we won't know how the relevant bit of the application is implemented currently.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to check if there is a custom image for that post (from the ACF field), and if there isn't take the first image from the post content.

I also understand (didn't check) that your current code works for the second case (get the first image from the post), so all you need is to add a query for the ACF image.

I would try something like this:

```
function catch_that_image() {
    global $post;
    
    $acf_image = get_field('your_acf_image_field_name');
    if (!empty($acf_image)) {
            return $image['url'];
    } else {
        $first_img = '';
        ob_start();
        ob_end_clean();
        $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+?src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*?>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
        $first_img = $matches[1][0];
            if(empty($first_img)) {
            $first_img = "/path/to/default.png";
            }
        return $first_img;
    }
}
```

Please note that in WordPress there are many advantages for using the native `wp_get_attachment_image()` with an image ID from ACF Image fields - you can find more information here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

Answer (score 0):

@Hillel, thanks.

I tried this instead. But my return result all in array. Is there something wrong. I modified from other code.

```
/**
     * Filters the title and alt message for thumbnails.
     *
     * @since   2.3.0
     *
     * @param   string  $post_title     Post tile used as thumbnail alt and title
     * @param   object  $result         Post Object
     */
    $post_title = apply_filters( 'tptn_thumb_title', $post_title, $result );

    $output    = '';
    $postimage = '';
    $pick      = '';
    if(! $postimage)
    {
        $args = [
                    'numberposts' => 1,
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'post_parent' => $post_title,
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
                ];
                $post_attachments = get_children($args);
    
                if ( ! empty($post_attachments) ) {
                    $output = array_shift($post_attachments->url);
    
                    return [
                        $postimage => get_attached_file($output->url),
                        $pick => get_post_meta($postimage->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true)
                    ];
                }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry my friend, but I don't understand how this code relates to your original question. Did you try the solution I suggested previously?

Comment: Yes. I tried the code but nothing in return. So I tried the above to get first attachment . But got array as return result.

Answer (score 0):

I try out this instead.

```
 if(!$postimage)
    {
        $header_image  = get_field( 'article_header_image', $result );
        if($header_image ){
            $postimage = ( $postimage['url'] );
            $pick .= 'first';
        }
        else{
            $postimage = tptn_get_first_image( $result->ID, $args['thumb_width'], $args['thumb_height'] );  // Get the first image.
            $pick      = 'firstchild';
        }
    }
```

How do I parse to URL?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j34BI.jpg

I tried the edited code. Not sure why it took the image randomly. Some is correct some is not.